# Alternative to getState for recurring variables in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I use `getState` to get a clientId that I need to include **in every api call**  right now. Problem is that this interrupts data flow as the app doesn't rerender when `clientId` changes. Do I have to manually get the clientId in every component that I need to include it in or is there a better alternative? (clientId is also in store and is fetched first when the user logs in)

Comment: How is the client ID used in each call? Is it a header? You can certainly put this in at a much lower level which means you wouldn't have to pull it in every component, but you would need to give a bit more information.

Comment: @James no its always different... Its some legacy api that doesn't make to much sense.

Comment: different in what way? Again, if you want help you need to give more information.

Comment: @James I need it in every post, put,get and delete request. Sometimes I have to include it in the url, sometimes in the headers and sometimes as form data. The api makes no sense but I can't touch that. I have 28 different routes that all use this id so I need it in my action.

Comment: ok, what's the actual problem though? Is it the fact you need to pull in the ID in every component? Are you aware of [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in React? This seems like it would be a good candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for the use of [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Here's a fictitious example of how you can set the client ID at a high level but reference it in nested components without having to query the Redux store each time using [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html):

**App**

```
const ClientContext = React.createContext(null);

function App(props) {
  return (
    <ClientContext.Provider value={props.clientId}>
      <MyApiComponent />
    </ClientContext>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = getState => ({
  clientId: getState().clientId
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(App);
```

So we only need to connect the `App` to the store to retrieve the client ID, then using `Context` we can make this value accessible to nested components. We can make use of [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to pull that value in to each component

```
function MyApiComponent() {
  const clientId = useContext(ClientContext);
  ...
  return <MyNestedApiComponent />;
}

function MyNestedApiComponent() {
  const clientId = useContext(ClientContext);
  ...
}
```

Whether it's function or class components you are using, the principle is the same - `Context` is used to share global state down to nested components.